# ScalaTest / SBT "testOnly com.acme.someText -- -n Slow" ignores all tests

Tags: scalatest

I'm trying to use ScalaTest's tagging feature to limit the scope of tests run in a test suite. Unfortunately it's not working at all; any syntax I've tried simply results in *no tests at all* running.

```
import org.scalatest.tagobjects._
"Ship service" should {
    "return to port" taggedAs(Slow) in {
        whenReady(client.getShip(shipId).invoke()) { ship =>
            whenReady(client.dock(ship.id).invoke()) { response =>
                response should be(Done)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `"return to port" taggedAs(org.scalatest.tagobjects.Slow)` but it makes no difference.

When I try to run only the `Slow` test in SBT, no tests run:

```
sbt:ship-service> testOnly "com.acme.ship.ShipSpec -- -n org.scalatest.tagobjects.Slow"
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 13 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
```

I've also tried:

```
sbt:ship-service> testOnly "com.acme.ship.ShipSpec -- -n Slow"
sbt:ship-service> testOnly com.acme.ship.ShipSpec -- -n Slow
```

No difference on the first one. On the second one (without quotes) every tests run, regardless of the tag applied (so all tests, included untagged and tagged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `org.scalatest.tagobjects.Slow` than it is implemented as `object Slow extends Tag("org.scalatest.tags.Slow")` so you need to execute `testOnly com.acme.ship.ShipSpec -- -n org.scalatest.tags.Slow` or define your own tags fe: `case object Slow extends Tag("Slow")`